# How to stop browser window from jumping on a #ID hash link - simplest javascript required

Tags: javascript, hash, window

Got a client who is strictly no javascript, but in this particular circumstance, I don't think I can avoid it.

I've got a "next / previous" featured area situation going on using CSS (overflow: hidden and position: absolute) - where the click next or previous (a href="#section...") then brings the relevant div ID into view -but, the browser jumps to the top of the screen which is really very annoying.

What's the simplest possible way to prevent this jumping from happening (with javascript) - yet still be usable for users with javascript turned off?

Comment: Whats wrong with a scrollbar?

Answer (score 4):

You can only solve this problem by a) Using JS or b) Getting rid of those anchor links.

If you chose choice a:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var link;
for(var i = 0, j = links.length; i < j; i++) {
    link = links[i];
    if(link.href.substring(0, 1) == '#') {
       link.onclick = function(e) {
          var ev = e || event;
          ev.preventDefault();
       };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jacob,
Thanks for your answer, but your code isn't stopping the jumping from happening. Any other suggestions?
Thanks,
L.

Answer (score 1):

**Just replace '#' link to 'javascript:void(0)' and your page will not gona scroll**

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title=" ">Link</a> // if you want no link, just like '#' link.
<a href="javascript:page(0);" title=" ">Link</a> // for link that you don't want to show.
```

**JS**

```
function page()
{ window.location.assign("home.html"); }
```